When should you use #include "example.h" in a C++ project?
I am working on a project that works with linked lists. I was running into some issues that I eventually traced back to the fact that I had circularly placed #include statements (ie. header file 1 has an includes header file 2 and header file 2 includes header file 1). This led me to the question of when do you actually need to use #include? Do you use it if you want to use the class it defines? Can you access a class without including its header file if you include another header file that does include it? (ie. you have a class named Car that includes the class Engine, can you access the Engine class from any file that includes Car.h?).
The current project I am working on has produced many errors related to certain files not being able to access certain parts of a class that I thought was available to it and I haven't been able to find a post on Stack Overflow that fully answers these questions.

My rule of thumb: Include every header file that declares/defines something that you use.  This can be tricky with circular dependencies but can be worked around as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/625801/4342498

5 rules, 1. Is A (inheritance), 2. Has A (member), 3. Templates, 4. Typedef, 5. Enums , otherwise you should use forward declarations.

I'm inclined to mark @NathanOliver's link as a duplicate of this question.

@DrewDormann I was tempted to and I wouldn't complain if someone did.  Just wasn't sure if needs more focus would be better as there is a lot of questions in this question.

... although, since #include simply places code at a specified location, and given the phrasing of this question... this question could almost be interpreted as "What sequential order should my lines of code have?"  Circular includes are always a symptom of not thinking about the order your code needs to be specified in.

You need to use an #include when it defines something that you need the full declaration of.  For example, when you need to create an instance of a type, or when you need to access members of an object, etc.
In some cases, you don't actually need the full declaration, such as when simply defining a pointer/reference to an object, in which case you can get away with using a forward declaration instead (which you usually have to use to fix circular references between objects).
In your example, if Car.h defines the Car class with an Engine* or Engine& data member, then Car.h could use a forward declaration of the Engine class without #include'ing the Engine.h header.  Any unit that then wants to access the features of a car's Engine can #include the Engine.h header for themselves.  A Car doesn't need to know what an Engine looks like to know that it has an Engine.
